# Importing Contracts: What to do with contract number?

Tags: import, auto-number, contracts

I have a customer who is already using Contracts that wants to import a bunch of their old Contracts.  One caveat is that the Salesforce auto-number for Contracts is prefixed with the current year, so all the old contracts have numbers that make them look like they were created this year.

Anyone know if there is a way to 'fix' the numbers so that they agree with the year they were imported?  Or even if we could make them '0000-####' so we know that they were imported?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[I faced the same issue with Order Number](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/77072/how-to-reset-a-standard-auto-number-field)

From salesforce help [link](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=modifying_standard_auto_number_fields.htm&language=en_US)

**[Modifying Standard Auto-Number Fields](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=modifying_standard_auto_number_fields.htm&language=en_US)**

The unique identifiers for solutions, cases, and contracts are standard auto-number fields. Each record is assigned a unique number with a specified format upon creation. You can modify the format and numbering for these auto-number fields.

1. From Setup, click Customize, select the appropriate tab link, and
   then click the Fields link.
2. Click Edit next to the name of the field
       in the Standard Fields list.
3. Enter a Display Format to control such
       formatting details as the minimum number of leading zeros as well as
       any prefix or suffix for the number. See Custom Field Attributes.
       **Format changes do not affect existing records; they are applied only
       to new records.**
4. Enter the number to be assigned to the next record
           that is created after you save your changes.
5. Click Save.

Comment: Cool, so I should just be able to temporarily change the auto number to the 0000-{0000} format and then change it back to {YYYY}-{0000} after I'm done.  Thanks!